# Which datastructure to use?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a scenario like this,
I need to store the count of the strings and I need to return the top ten strings which has the max count,

for example,

```
String    Count
---------------------------------
String1   10
String2   9
String3   8 
.
.
.
String10  1
```

I was thinking of using the hashtable for storing the string and its count but it would be difficult to retrieve the top ten strings from it as I have to again loop through it to find them.

Any other suggestions here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a sorted map like

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> strings
```

where the key is the frequency value and the value the list of strings that occur with that frequency.

Then, loop through the map and, with an inner loop through the value lists until you've seen 10 strings. Those are the 10 most frequent one's.

---

With the *additional* requirement that the algorithm should support *updates* of frequencies: add the strings to a map like `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the string and the value the actual frequency (increment the value if you see a string again). *After that* copy the key/value pairs to the map I suggested above.

Comment: How would you update such a structure while counting string? (Though it's not explicitly mentioned in question, it's often the use case).

Comment: Lets take the scenario where I count the frequency of the strings as it comes and add it to this map and lets say there are 10 strings each of them are occuring ten times then this map will have entries like          1- string1....string10, 2-string1...string10 similarly it will have the same entry for all the values in the map, is there any optimized solution for this.

Comment: @ffriend - as you said, that was not an requirement. With that additional requirement I'd use a value holder class like Brinnis suggested, define a comparator and store the value holder in some list and sort it after all has been counted.

Comment: @Lokn - you describe a different scenario. What you asked for was a solution to a problem where you already have the counts for all strings.

Comment: @Andreas_D- sorry if I had not made it clear but that was the usecase.

Answer (score 4):

Priority Que.

You can make a class to put in it:

```
public class StringHolder{
    private String string;
    private int value;

    //Compare to and equals methods
}
```

then it will sort when you insert and it is easy to get the top 10.

Comment: What if the string is already there, in that i just need to increase the count, how to find that particular string object?

Comment: That would be a relativity slow operation.  You would have to iterate through all the object looking for that String.  If you did this a lot a hash map would probably be better.

You have to decide if you want the get top 10 to be slower, or if updating something already in the data structure to be slower.

Comment: @Lokn: you can count strings with a hash map and then use priority queue to find N most frequent of them. That would be 2 passes, but asymptotic running time will still be amortized O(n).

Answer (score 0):

For any task like "find N top items" priority queues are perfect solution. See Java's [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but i guess that the most suitable and elegant class for your needs is guava's 
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html

Comment: TreeMultiset can be used, but it's got more overhead than HashMultiset.  The ordering it imposes is on the actual keys, not the count.  So the overhead you pay for the key ordering is wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Guava has a HashMultiset which would be very useful for this.

```
HashMultiset<String> ms = Hashmultiset.create();
ms.add(astring);
ms.add(astring, times);


ImmutableMultiset<String> ims = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(ms);

// iterator through the first 10 elements, and they will be your top 10
// from highest to lowest.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Max Heap data structure for this. Put it all into the max heap, and make successive 10 (or whatever n) removals.

And if you intend to keep reusing the data once it's loaded into memory, it might be worth the expense of sorting by value instead of a heap.